# Cannot display Classic ASP website locally

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP website that I need to run locally.  My OS is Windows 7 and using Visual Studio 2010.
In the IIS under the Default Web Site, I added the application in the folder, classic_asp_website. I created a Classic ASP application pool to connect to the website. I can successfully test the connection by going into the 'Basic Settings' and 'Test Settings'.  The user credentials are valid.
The tree in IIS looks like this:

```
Application Pools
Sites
  Default Web Sites
    classic_asp_website (folder)
      Paging (folder)
        Paging
```

I want to step thru the web site by 'Attaching to a Process' but I can't get the website to display.
When I type into the browser the url `http://localhost/classic_asp_net/Paging/Paging`, the header displays with our logo but on the rest of the web page it says;

```
Server Error 'Default Web Site'" Error: 404.
```

The URL is correct. When I expand the Paging folder in the IIS, the folders are all there. The webpage is `default.asp`.  Even when I add this to the URL, I get the same error.
I don't understand why it wouldn't display the webpage.

In addition, I made sure that ASP was enabled under the Window Feature within the Application Development folder.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Checking the log files from the IIS, the default page seems to load
Here is the text:

```
/classic_asp_website/Paging/Paging/default.asp - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/6.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 200 0 0 35
```

I am taking the '200' number to mean there were not errors.
Then there are 3 - '404 errors and 1 '500 error.
I don't understand why it can't find the files. I added them to the appropriate folders.  Here are the rest of the errors:

```
2015-01-30 21:11:03 ::1 GET /Common/Images/Background.gif - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/6.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 404 0 2 3
2015-01-30 21:11:03 ::1 GET /classic_asp_website/Paging/Paging/ASP/MainPager.asp UserID=|1|ASP_0131|Disallowed_Parent_Path 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/6.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) **500** 0 0 10
2015-01-30 21:11:03 ::1 GET **/Common/toolbar.asp** - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/6.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) **404** 0 2 40
2015-01-30 21:11:03 ::1 GET **/Common/Images/Background.gif** - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/6.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) **404** 0 2 2
```

I don't know what 'Disallowed Parent Path' means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, what `Disallowed Parent Path` means is you can't do something like this:

```
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="../../commonLibrary.asp"-->
```

meaning going up into the parent directory when including files. This is considered a security risk.

If your code does this and you are okay with it, you can allow it, in IIS Manager open the `ASP` icon and change:

```
Enable Parent Paths    True
```

Comment: Thank you!  Let me try that.

Comment: It got rid if the Enable Parent Paths error.  But it failed to create the object strUserID when setting the server varilable:

Comment: It got rid if the Enable Parent Paths error.  But it failed to create the object strUserID when setting the server varilable:  Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER").  How do I set the windows authentication?

Comment: Open the Authentication icon in IIS Manager and enable Windows Authentication. If it is not there, you have to install it first using Windows Features.

Comment: thanks.  got it.  The userID is showing correctly in the log file but there is still a CreateObject failure for some reason.

Comment: If you have the site running on a server, just compare the settings and try to match them locally.

Comment: I compared the settings and I had to add a 'Common' folder to find the 2 files that it was looking for.  I am now getting a CreateObject failure when it tries to create the object, DomainInfo.Info, using this line of code:   Set oDomainInfo = Server.CreateObject("DomainInfo.Info").  Is this a permission thing?

Comment: Are you using 64Bit windows? If so, the COM object DomainInfo may be 32bit only. Set your application pool to enable 32bit Applications in the advanced settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My windows 7 is 32-bit.   I looked in the Advanced Settings of the application pool but I don't see where there is an option to enable 32-bit applications.

Comment: You wont have it if its 32bit, because you don't need it if your OS is already 32bit. You may want to check whether DomainInfo.Info is registered on your machine. Check the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`,

Comment: No.  There is no reference to DomainInfo.Info.  How do I register it?

Comment: On the production server, there are cabinet files called DomainInfo.  Do I need to copy them and put them on my local computer somewhere?

Comment: check the registry on the live server, and see what binary DomainInfo is pointing to. Copy that dll (or exe) to your machine and register it with `regsvr32.exe name.dll`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Found the file, copied and registered!  Most importantly it works! :)  THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

I have got this problem recently,its because your site has settings to PREVENT 'Parent Path' for ASP. (I guess relative paths are used in your code)

To Fix it:
1. Open your IIS manager.

2. click on your site on the left pane. (my one is "Default WebSite")
3. click 'ASP' icon on your right
4. change 'Enable Parent Path' to true.

It will fix your problem.